# C++ segfault only if cout not used

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault

Why does the following code give segmentation fault only when I don't have a cout statement (run with g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp):
Why does the following code give segmentation fault only when I don't have a cout statement (run with g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                   
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


struct node {
        int data;
        node *left;
        node *right;

        node(int d, node *l, node *r) : data{d}, left{l}, right{r} {}
};

node* findNode(node *root, node *find) {

    if (!root) return nullptr;

    if (root->data == find->data) {
            return root;
    }   

    node *left, *right;

    if (root->left) left = findNode(root->left, find);
    if (root->right) right = findNode(root->right, find);

    // Uncomment this to avoid a segfault. Why ?
    //cout << "left = " << left << " right = " << right <<  " find = " << find << endl;

    if (left && left->data == find->data) {
            return left;
    }   
    if (right && right->data == find->data) {
            return right;
    }   
    return nullptr;
}


int main() {

    node *newNode1 = new node(20, nullptr, nullptr);
    node *newNode2 = new node(60, nullptr, nullptr);

    node *root = new node(50, newNode1, newNode2);

    findNode(root, newNode1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code compiles and runes well for me

Comment: You have potentially uninitialized `left` and `right`, leading to undefined behavior. So weird stuff is par for the course.

Comment: You have UB and are leaking memory. Investigate smart pointers (and stl containers) and initialize your variables.

Comment: Run your program from debugger, when it crashes inspect call stack and variable values. Imagine you are working on a large project. Are you going to carefully read thousands of lines of code trying to find the issue every time your program crashes?

Comment: Well, for me it gives segfault only when the cout line is uncommented. But thanks Paul, will do that

Comment: . o O (does GCC not warn about uninitialized variables?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `node *left, *right;` produce uninitialized pointers, their value is undefined. It seems like you are relying on them being initially `nullptr`, but this is not necessarily the case.

When you reach the condition `if(left && left->data == find->data)`, unless `left` was assigned earlier, you are checking the value of an uninitialized variable (`left`). Reading from an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, which means that it can do anything including crashing, appearing to work fine or something totally unpredictable. The resulting behavior can change at any time for any reason, including changes that appear unrelated to the problem. It's futile to try to reason on *why* a program with undefined behavior does what it does beyond simply noting that it is undefined behavior.

One solution is to initialize your pointers to null so that they are never in an uninitialized state :

```
node *left = nullptr;
node *right = nullptr;
```

Comment: "This is undefined behavior, which means that it can do anything" - strictly speaking it is *worse*; when one part of your program invokes UB the compiler is allowed to do *whatever it wants* - including compiling *other* parts of your code to something you did not expect - UB is *not* localized to where you write it, but affects *all* of your code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I assumed "anything" covered pretty much everything.

Comment: right. I just felt a need to be explicit. UB is often misunderstood to affect just the code that exhibits UB, where in fact it can affect all of the program.

Comment: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) (sort of).

Comment: Thanks, this avoids the segmentation fault.

Comment: @François Andrieux : yep.

Comment: @Tomas Gudmundsson : I hope you realize that just because a program does not segfault, does not mean that it *works*. Just like "it compiles" does not mean "it'll do what you want" it to.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I know. I made this post to help me understand why the behaviour was different. The program is irrelevant and just a sample I made in few min, and not the same as the one where the bug occurred in a larger program.

Comment: @Tomas Gudmundsson : trying to reason about the behaviour of a program with UB is pointless.

Comment: @JesperJuhl true, better avoid UB